# how do I get a mat-icon to align properly with the text in a mat-card-title?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

**how do I get a mat-icon to align properly with the text in a mat-card-title?** What I would like is for the home icon to line up properly with the the text "The 20 Minute Rule". It seems like this is something people want to do, put icons in their header and I was hoping it would just work out the box. I will try to figure it out and post an answer.

```
 <mat-card-header>

        <mat-card-subtitle>
            Rule # {{rule.id}}
        </mat-card-subtitle>
        <mat-card-title style="vertical-align: top;">

            <mat-icon style="border:1px solid red;" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon"
                fontIcon="home"></mat-icon>

            <a style="border:1px solid red" *ngIf="showLink" routerLink="/rule/{{rule.id}}">{{rule.name}}</a>

        </mat-card-title>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this, not sure if this is correct, but it works. It still seems of a pixel or two, but I can manage

mat-card-title,
mat-card-subtitle {
a {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}

```
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}


mat-icon {
    margin-right: 3px;
}
//This is what I had to do to get icons to line up. Is this the best way?
* {
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid red; //TODO Remove this
}
```

}

[image]